# jQuery mobile panel doesn't close fully only on Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbh1rn33/

I have a weird issue with jQm panel.

An opened panel doesn't close fully. See below image:

[image]

Strangely, this only happens on Android browser, and not on PC (Chrome, IE).

Is this a bug with jQm or have I done something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1>Test Page</h1>
            <div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup">  
                <a href="#search_condition_panel" id="search_condition_btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-grid">Show Options</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        </div>
        <div data-position-fixed="true" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="search_condition_panel" data-position="right">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="search-condition-select-brand">Brand</label>
                <select id="search-condition-select-brand" name="search-condition-select-brand" data-mini="true">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code worked fine on my nexus Android 5.1.1
Which browser and OS version are you trying it on?

Comment: Galqxy S4 Android 4.4.2 default browser.

Comment: I tried to emulate the website on my PC as a Samsung S4 in Chrome with no success in reproducing the issue.  I also tried the stock browser on my Note 4 without success.  Is this also happening in other browsers on your phone?

Comment: @John Carpenter This only happens on stock browser. I just tried it on Android chrome and the site works fine. Phone model is SHV-E300S if that helps.

Comment: My horrendous workaround is to reload the page on panel close:

`$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
    $('[data-role="panel"]').on("panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
        location.reload();
    });
});`

Comment: Look like jQuery UI bug, for 1.4.2 it can not be [reproduced](http://jsbin.com/mocice/2/) and it [reproduced](http://jsbin.com/mocice/1/) for 1.4.5. Test on my Galaxy S4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like jQuery UI bug, for 1.4.2 it can not be [reproduced](http://jsbin.com/mocice/2/) and it [reproduced](http://jsbin.com/mocice/1/) for 1.4.5. Test on my Galaxy S4

The main difference in your case is in сss properties of class `.ui-panel-closed`:

```
/* 1.4.5 */
.ui-panel-closed {
  width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
/* 1.4.2 */
.ui-panel-closed {
  width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And if you reset `left` css property for `.ui-panel-closed` all will work [fine](http://jsbin.com/mocice/4/):

```
.ui-panel-closed {
  left: auto !important; // left auto fix problem
}
```

Comment: Wow yeah that fixed the problem. I'm wondering how you went about investigating this issue on the phone

Comment: Nothing special, just check css properties. On Android you can use [remote debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) for Chrome or bugly [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) for Android Default Browser